# Swig: interface simple C++ class that returns vector

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am completely new in using swig, so forgive me if it seems simple.

I want to write an interface for a class in `C++` that get and return a vector of double:

```
/*  example.h file */
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

class my_class 
{
    private:    
        int N;
    public:
        my_class(){ }
        std::vector<double> half(const std::vector<double>& ); 
};

/* example.cpp  file */
#include "example.h"

std::vector<double> my_class::half(const std::vector<double>& v) {
    std::vector<double> w(v);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<w.size(); i++)
        w[i] /= 2.0;
    return w;
}
```

and the **example.i** interface file

```
%module example

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std {
    %template(DoubleVector)  vector<double>;
}


#include "example.h"
```

Then I tried to use the module in python:

```
import example
A = example.my_class()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d2af384d4adf> in <module>()
----> 1 example.my_class()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'my_class'
```

Thanks for any guide or comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line in `example.i` should be `%include "example.h"` not `#include "example.h"`.